# Language Server Spec Finder Errors When Launching Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I would just like to understand what's happening below. I am using MacOs and recently switched from bash to zsh. And then I installed jupyterlab-lsp. Can you please enlighten me?

```
    [W 14:27:11.102 LabApp] Failed to fetch commands from language server spec finder`bash-language-server`:
        expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
    [W 14:27:11.108 LabApp] Failed to fetch commands from language server spec finder`dockerfile-language-server-nodejs`:
        expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
    [W 14:27:11.113 LabApp] Failed to fetch commands from language server spec finder`javascript-typescript-langserver`:
        expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
    [W 14:27:11.125 LabApp] Failed to fetch commands from language server spec finder`unified-language-server`:
        expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
    [W 14:27:11.129 LabApp] Failed to fetch commands from language server spec finder`vscode-css-languageserver-bin`:
        expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
    [W 14:27:11.133 LabApp] Failed to fetch commands from language server spec finder`vscode-html-languageserver-bin`:
        expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
    [W 14:27:11.138 LabApp] Failed to fetch commands from language server spec finder`vscode-json-languageserver-bin`:
        expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
    [W 14:27:11.142 LabApp] Failed to fetch commands from language server spec finder`yaml-language-server`:
        expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
    [I 14:27:11.193 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /Users/emilolbinado/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
    [I 14:27:11.193 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/emilolbinado/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
    [I 14:27:11.195 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/emilolbinado
    [I 14:27:11.195 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
    [I 14:27:11.195 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=95a48a55a6638a48cbfa24c95106903144ffaafe10a65652
    [I 14:27:11.195 LabApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=95a48a55a6638a48cbfa24c95106903144ffaafe10a65652
    [I 14:27:11.195 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
    [C 14:27:11.202 LabApp] 

        To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
            file:///Users/emilolbinado/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-8098-open.html
        Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
            http://localhost:8888/?token=95a48a55a6638a48cbfa24c95106903144ffaafe10a65652
         or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=95a48a55a6638a48cbfa24c95106903144ffaafe10a65652
    Opening in existing browser session.
    [I 14:27:14.645 LabApp] Build is up to date
    [I 14:27:21.183 LabApp] Kernel started: 5c355536-12b0-41de-8c81-cc2afef6a85c
    [I 14:27:21.218 LabApp] Kernel started: 9505d56b-0f5a-43f4-970e-990fa0852522
```

Comment: I have the same problem; I just posted the problem on jupyterlab-lsp's github: https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp/issues/121

Comment: Thank you for leading me to this link... Still not able to find the fix on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because jupyter server is unable to find the language servers. As in my case, jupyter is installed and maintained using conda environment(miniconda) under /opt/miniconda3/, whilst my nodejs is sitting under /usr/local/. Ideally, if you are already using conda manager, you will want to uninstall nodejs completely and reinstall it using conda. Otherwise, remove the entire anaconda/conda and then reinstall python (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-381/) and jupyter using either pip or brew depending how/where you installed nodejs.

I was able to resolve my issue following below steps:

1.) Completely uninstall node js. I was able to do it by running `nvm uninstall <version>` or if you are using homebrew, run `brew uninstall node` and then `rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm` on terminal. Additionally, you can follow below reference: [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

2.) Reinstall nodejs. `conda install -c conda-forge nodejs`

3.) Install the language servers. See reference: https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp/blob/master/LANGUAGESERVERS.md#installing-language-servers

4.) Restart terminal and run jupyter lab.

Now this is the best answer that I have that was able to resolve my issue.